# Which constraints should basis functions coefficients satisfy so that the resulting function is bounded?

Tags: linear-algebra, convex-optimization, convex-geometry

I have a function f expressed in terms of Fourier sine series as $f(x) = \sum_{i=1}^M u_i \, sin(i \pi x)$ in a bounded interval, say $\Omega = [0,1]$. $f$ should satisfy the constraint:
\begin{equation}
-1 \leq f(x) \leq 1 \quad \forall x \in \Omega
\end{equation}
Is there any way to express the constraints on $a_i$?

What I have been doing so far is to grid the space with $N$ equally spaced points $x_1,\ldots,x_n$ and impose the constraint for each grid point $x_i$ so that I can express it as a linear set of inequalities on the coefficients:

\begin{equation}
A \mathbf{u}\leq\mathbf{1}
\end{equation}

where $A \in \mathbb{R}^{2N \times M}$ and $N\gg M$.

I have the feeling that most of these constraints are redundant. I was wondering if I can express this condition with less constraints or if it is possible to approximate the convex feasible region with fewer inequalities.

Comment: I do not have enough point for a comment. But you question would be easier to answer,or easier to start answering,with a concrete example for f.